# Flutter StreamController.broadcast, weird behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-streambuilder

I have a static StreamController.

```
static StreamController<OrgSetting> setting = StreamController.broadcast();

void updateSetting(OrgSetting newSetting){
    setting.add(newSetting);
}
```

I have a page that uses the above streamController to display some value inside a listView.

```
StreamBuilder(stream : MyInfo.setting.stream, builder : (context, snapshot) {
     if(snapShot.hasData){
        return someView();
     }else {
        return defaultView();
     }
}
```

When I add a data to the streamController before I get into this ListView, it always says that the snapShot.hasData is false.
When I add a data to the streamController after I get into this ListView, it works as I intented.

Is there some concept I'm missing about the streamController? Why is this happening?

Comment: try to put the data into the sink,  `setting.sink.add(newSetting)`

Comment: @A-E If i do so, in the streamBuilder's hasData is false,I can access the sink to get the last data, am I right?